# How to convert vb6 'vbFromUnicode' to string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, vb6

I got as code in VB6, which need to be converted in C#. I have googled it but didn't get any concrete answer.

VB code:

```
Dim strTemp = StrConv(strTemp , vbFromUnicode)
```

I tried to do like this in c#:

```
var strTemp = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.StringToBSTR(strTemp);
```

I think this is not correct.

Any suggestions? what would be the correct interpetation of above vb6 code in c#.

Comment: You think it isn't correct? Does it work?

Comment: Not giving the expected result, and also not seem quite right to me...

Comment: What is the expected result, and the actual result?

Comment: Also, what is `vbFromUnicode`?

Comment: It was not uncommon in VB6 to store a Byte() array in a string.  StrConv() then converts it to a string.  This is not possible anymore in VB.NET, if a conversion is necessary then you must start with Byte() and use Encoding.GetString().  In effect, without knowing anything where strTemp came from, this snippet does nothing at all and can be deleted.

Comment: Well we know that this isn't VB6 code anyway, since it isn't a "dynamic" (scripting) language like VB.Net and C# so the `Dim` statement doesn't support inline value assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conversion of a Unicode string to an Ansi string, by system default code page.

```
StrConv(strTemp , vbFromUnicode)
```

In C#, you need to found out the default code page by [ANSICodePage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.ansicodepage(v=vs.110).aspx) from current culture

```
int codepage = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage;
byte[] convertedBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding(codepage).GetBytes(unicodeString);
string convertedAsciiString = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(convertedBytes);
```